# Application of Liouville's Theorem to Weierstrass $\wp$ function

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-functions

We fix a lattice $\Gamma \subset \mathbb{C}$ and a period parallelogram of it and we pick nine distinct points $\omega_1, \dots, \omega_9 \in \mathbb{C}$ inside this parallelogram.
We now insert the Weierstrass $\wp$ function and its derivative $\wp '$ into a homogeneous polynomial $f(x,y,z) = x^a y^b z^c$ of degree $d$ (i.e. $a+b+c = d$). So we get $f(\wp(z), \wp'(z),1) = \wp(z)^a \wp'(z)^b$ for a complex number $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

This is holomorphic away from the lattice points and has a pole of order at most $3d$ in the origin. Besides that, it is given that it has a zero of order at least $m$ at each of the points $\omega_1,\dots,\omega_9$.

The claim is now the following:
If $d < 3m$, then it follows from Liouville's Theorem (*) that $f(\wp(z), \wp'(z),1)$ is identically zero.

Whereas Liouville's Theorem (*) states that over any period parallelogram the double periodic meromorphic function $f(\wp(z), \wp'(z),1)$ has the same number of poles as zeros (counting multiplicities).

So if $p =$ number of poles and $n =$ number of zeros, we have $3d \geq p = n \geq 9m$ by Liouville. But on the other side we also have $3d < 9m$.
I don't know how I can conclude from this, that $f(\wp(z), \wp'(z),1) = 0$, so maybe someone else has an idea ?

Comment: What is your polynomial $f(x,y)$ ? If it is $f(x ,y) = x^a y^b$ then clearly $f(\wp(z),\wp'(z))$ isn't identically zero. Indeed $f(\wp(z),\wp'(z)) $ is constant iff it is holomorphic iff it has no pole at $z=0$, which happens precisely when $f(x,y ) = (y^2-4x^3+a x+b) h(x,y)$ where $a,b$ are the constants such that $\wp(z) = z^{-2} + \frac{a}{20} z^2+\frac{b}{28}z^4+O(z^6)$

Comment: I can't quite follow you.. $\wp(z)$ has a pole of order 2 in 0 and $\wp'(z)$ as a pole of order 3 in 0... so if I insert them in $f(\wp(z),\wp'(z),1) = \wp(z)^a \cdot \wp'(z)^b$, I get that $f(\wp(z),\wp'(z),1)$ has a pole of order $(2a+3b)$ in $0$, since these are the properties of multiplying functions with a pole. Or am I wrong ?

Comment: Sure that's why I said $\wp(z)^a \wp'(z)^b$ isn't identically $0$. But $\wp'(z)^2-4\wp(z)^3-a \wp(z)-b$ **is identically zero**. Also above I meant $f(x,y ) = (y^2-4x^3+a x+b) h(x,y)+C$

Comment: oh ok... I know that $f$ must a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$, so it can't be your polynomial...

Comment: I am trying to prove Lemma 2.50 on page 74 ( http://www.math.ens.fr/~benoist/refs/Mukai.pdf ), and the question I posed above is the step in the proof I do not understand... there is another condition $m (\omega_1 + \dots + \omega_9) \notin \Gamma$, but I thought I need this condition for something else, that's why I did not mention it in my question above

Comment: You didn't define any polynomial, except $f(x,y,z) = x^a y^b z^c$ which as I have shown doesn't make sense. And again $f(\wp(z),\wp'(z))$ is identically zero iff $f(x,y ) = (y^2-4x^3+a x+b) h(x,y)$ for some polynomial $h$

Comment: Well, in the statement there is no defined polynomial... its just said that $f$ is homogeneous of degree $d$ and f(x,y,z) has a zero at each $(\wp(\omega_i), \wp'(\omega_i),1)$ of multiplicity at least $m$... but by liouvilles theorem it must follow that $f(\wp(z), \wp'(z),1)$ is identically  zero..

Comment: You said so : $F(z) = f(\wp(z), \wp'(z))$ is meromorphic on the torus, if it is non-zero then it has the same number of poles and zeros (counted with multiplicity). It has at most $3d$ poles, thus if it has more than $3d$ zeros it must be identically zero. The "same number of zeros/poles" is not Liouville theorem but the argument principle.

Comment: ahhh :) thank you very much!!